# Close Forms in Word by clicking away (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word, activex, eventhandler

I am new to VBA and have a document with multiple **ActiveX buttons** that each open a form with some infotext. Instead of having to click the 'x' of each window the user should be able to close a window by **'clicking away'**.

(There may be better ways to display 'infoboxes', but the MsgBox is even worse since it also triggers a sound alert. I chose the ActiveX button bc a image can be loaded easily)

[image]

Comment: MsgBox only sounds an alert if you use the wrong parameters.

Answer (score 0):

## This works

After extensiv research (but still no real expierience) I came up with this solution:

1. Insert ActiveX Button, right click and select 'view code'
2. You should be directed to the VBA under '**ThisDocument**' in the corresponding click-Sub. Here create a new Form (see Step 3) and show the Form to windows. Using 0 is required, else the window won't be shut later. The second Sub is needed for step 4 and 5.

   ```
    Private Sub cmdHelp_Click()
      Dim frm As New frmHelp
      frm.Show 0  ' with 0 it is possible to unload window, with 1 not!
      Set frm = Nothing        
    End Sub

    Private Sub DocumentActivateEvent()
        Call Register_Event_Handler 
    End Sub
   ```
3. Create new Form. The Form Name must be 'frmHelp' as specified above. Now when the created button is pressed, this form will be displayed.
4. To close open forms a **eventHandler** is needed, that is triggered, when the Word screen is activated (switch from Form to Word). To close the form, a loop over all Forms is chosen. Insert this into a new **Class** 'Class1':

   ```
    Private WithEvents app As Application

    Private Sub app_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
        'Debug.Print "Event occurred!"
        Dim frm As UserForm

        For Each frm In UserForms
            If frm.Enabled Then
                Unload frm  'form is unloaded
            End If
        Next frm
    End Sub   

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()    
        Set app = Application
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()    
        Set app = Nothing
    End Sub
   ```
5. Create a new **Module** 'modEventHandler1' with:

   ```
    Private X As Class1

    Sub Register_Event_Handler()
        Set X = New Class1
    End Sub

    Sub Unregister_Event_Handler()
        Set X = Nothing
    End Sub
   ```

That should do it! Restart word or manually execute the 'Register_Event_Handler' Makro. Now, when the 'DocumentAcrivateEvent' from step 2. is triggered, the EventHandler is initialised. Hope I could help.